# $x^2 + 2 = 5y$ ($x$ and $y$ positive integers)

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

**Question**:

Determine all positive integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the equation 
$x^2 + 2 = 5y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: When is $5y - 2$ a square? Modulo 5 this is $5y - 2 = 3$, but squares mod 5 are always 0, 1 or 4 so the equation has no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\ \  x^2 \equiv\ \ldots\ \:(mod\ 5)\ $ versus $\rm\ \mathbb Z^2\ \equiv\ \{0,\:\pm1,\:\pm2\}^2\ \equiv\ \ldots \ \:(mod\ 5)$